# database: Generate a unique string directly in the database via query and field formatting

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

I have a field with those attributes:

```
name "unique"
type "varchar"
size "15"
index "INDEX"
```

I want to create an index field that automatically generates alpha numeric characters.
At the moment I manually enter a randomly generated code through:"INSERT INTO table (unique) VALUES (MD5(RAND()))"
This method have a problem:
if the random code (result of expression MD5(RAND())) exist in the database the data can not be added to the database. Can I order the database to generate a "unique" string automatically?

Answer (score 0):

extremely unlikely to to get duplicates:

`MD5(uniqid());`

but do read the warnings on the [manual page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

An alternatives is mysqls own `UUID()`

Comment: php.net says:Warning
This function tries to create unique identifier, but it does not guarantee 100% uniqueness of return value. My real problem is the danger of duplicate  id. That function have a risk of a duplicate: i can't use uniqid().

Comment: how many db rows are you creating? `uniqid (rand(), true)` the odds of a collisition are small, very very small,

Comment: Use UUID() instead off MD5().. UUID() almost has zero risk off duplication.

Comment: Now: 9, maybe they will arrive at 13-14.

Comment: @RaymondNijland not a 0 risk. 9? 13 .. i dont think you have a collision risk with such a tiny count. i find it hard to believe you encountered a collision with `MD5(RAND()))` with a sample of 9

Comment: @smith but they are test fields, they could even exceed 50k.